# Set text from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set the label text as empty as it depend on the situation.
In ascx file I set as below code:

```
<td runat="server" id="tdAvailableD" class="text-center" style ="font-size: 12px">
  <asp:Label ID="lblAvailable" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="true" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
```

In ascx.cs file I set as below code:

```
private void CheckQuantityError()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dlDiscountedProducts.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            {
                DropDownList qty = (DropDownList)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("ddlQuantity");
                HiddenField productId = (HiddenField)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("hdnProductID");
                HiddenField discountRuleId = (HiddenField)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("hdnDiscountRuleId");
                //HiddenField AvailStatus = (HiddenField)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("hdnAvailStatus");
                //HtmlGenericControl spanAvailStatus = (HtmlGenericControl)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("spanAvailStatus");
                Label lblOutofStockError = (Label)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("lblOutofStockError");
                Label lblAvailable = (Label)dlDiscountedProducts.Items[i].FindControl("lblAvailable");
                DCShoppingCartItem shoppingCartItem = new DCShoppingCartItem();

                if (null != Product)
                {
                    bool status = false;

                    try
                    {
                        using (new AcsServiceContextScope())
                        {
                            status = AcsServiceContextScope.Current.Products.GetAxStockAvailability(new GetStockAvailabilityRequest()
                            {
                                ModelNumber = Product.ModelNumber,
                                Quantity = 1,
                                ProductId = Product.Id
                            }).StockStatus;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logging.EventLogger.LogEvent(ex);
                    }

                    if (status == true)
                    {
                        //spanAvailStatus.Attributes["class"] = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove";//available
                        lblAvailable.Visible = true;
                        lblAvailable.Text = "In Stock";
                        lblOutofStockError.Visible = true;
                        lblAlert.Visible = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //spanAvailStatus.Attributes["class"] = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok";//not available
                        lblAvailable.Visible = true;
                        lblAvailable.Text = "No Stock";
                        lblOutofStockError.Visible = true;
                        lblAlert.Visible = true;
                        //qty.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

                    }
                }


            }
        }

    }
```

but the text not display in page.The function should show, if the item have quantity then it will show in stock.

Comment: In which function do you put that code? You will probably have to post the whole code behind file.

Comment: Updated. Please refer again.

Comment: I have no idea how CheckQuantityError is called unless you post the whole file.

Comment: You can also put a breakpoint on the line you set the text on and see if it hits when you debug the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping `lblAvailable` inside an update panel and try posting back the page.

The reason could be setting the text in label is not posted back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is Coming to the `lblAvailable` properly.
If it is?  then put the

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <td runat="server" id="tdAvailableD" class="text-center" style ="font-size: 12px">
  <asp:Label ID="lblAvailable" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="true" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then in `.cs` use this

```
UpdatePanel.Update();
```

and remove `Text` and `ForeColor` properties rather do it from `.cs`
u can even give different colors

```
lblAvailable.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;//or red when not in stock
```

Comment: u might need reference